# What type does & return for an Array Parameter inside a C Function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, operators

When passing an Array Argument to a Function, it's memory address is copied into an Array Parameter. Because of this:

- `sizeof()` returns the size of the entire array for the Array Argument (inside caller)
- `sizeof()` returns the size of a pointer for the Array Parameter (inside called Function)

My question is, what type is the Array Parameter inside the Function? And more specifically, what type is returned when using the **&** Operator on an Array Parameter? It's not a Pointer to Array of Type, nor is it a Pointer to Type, as shown in this code (labeled **BAD**):

```
void doSomething(int arrayParam[10]);

int main()
{
    int array[10] = { 0 };
    int (*arrayPtr)[] = &array;         // OK
    printf("%p\n", array);              // 0x7fff5fbff790
    doSomething(array);

    return 0;
}

void doSomething(int arrayParam[10])
{
    printf("%p\n", arrayParam);         // 0x7fff5fbff790

    int (*arrayPtr)[] = &arrayParam;    // BAD: Initialization from incompatible pointer type
    int * element0Ptr = &arrayParam;    // BAD: Initialization from incompatible pointer type

    element0Ptr = arrayParam;           // OK
    element0Ptr = &arrayParam[0];       // OK
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, when you use an array, it decays to a pointer to its initial element.  So, if you have:

```
void f(int* x);

int array[10];
int* initial_element_of_array = array; // array decays to a pointer to initial element
f(array);                              // same here
```

`f()` gets a pointer to the initial element of `array`.

Something that is rather confusing at first is that if a function has a parameter that is of an array type (like if you had `void f(int x[])`), this is actually converted such that it is exactly the same as `void f(int* x)`.  There is no difference between them:  array type parameters are the same as pointer type parameters.

Once you pass an array to a function, all you have is a pointer to its initial element, so if you apply the `&` operator to the `int*`, you get an `int**` (a pointer to an `int*`).

Comment: Note this can get really horrible with things like `typedef int foo[1]; void f(foo x);` Now someone reasonable would expect `&x` to have type `foo *`, but it actually has an extra level of indirection (it's `int **` instead of `int (*)[1]`). A very practical version of this problem arises with `va_list`, which is often defined as an array type...